# SharePoint/Infopath Save button

Tags: infopath, approval, save, button

I have an InfoPath form linked with a SharePoint 2013 list.  The idea is that the user clicks on the new document, fills out part of the form, then submits it via clicking on a "Submit" button  This works fine.  But the form must go through three more levels of approval before it's done.  The Travel Coordinator, Manager, and FCO must concur prior to completion.  For their sections I set up a drop down for Concur/Non Concur for the sake of SP Designer workflows.  But my client would like to see a button similar to the Submit button from earlier, but simply have it save their updates.  I know that they could easily click Save in the upper left corner...but this is what they want.

Now, is it possible for me to designate separate buttons on the same form whose sole function is to save the updates made, without affecting the original "Submit" button?

I know this is a mouthful, but any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you so much!!

Best,

Chris

Mike,

Thanks for the response.  Here's a more detailed description of what I'm after:

Thank you so much for the answer.  I'll show you some screen shots here to show you what I'm talking about:

Step One

User Clicks on "New Travel Document" - Coded to change the name from "New Document"

Step Two

User fills out information for his/her upcoming travel.

Step Three

User clicks the Submit button (Main Submit).  The form is then displayed on the SP list - kicks off the workflows.

Step Four

The Travel Coordinator receives an email indicating that they need to review the form.  Once they do, they need to Concur or Non-Concur (drop down list on the form).

Issue:  The Client wants to have a button similar to the original submit button, rather than have the Travel Coordinator click 'save' at the top of the screen.  I know, it seems like an unnecessary step.  BUT, I want to create a button that has a Save function...maybe Save & Close that I can place in the middle of the form.

If you wouldn't mine, could you please walk me through adding a save button to an InfoPath form?

I very much appreciate your help.

Chris

Comment: Here are the docs for adding a button. The functionality I described of setting a field and then submitting would be the "rules and custom code" option: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/add-buttons-cae06cc2-a708-47b2-889a-e33d82b5f0e7

Comment: Also, for future reference, please put notes to people in the comments. That way they get alerted, and it doesn't clutter up the main answer.

Comment: Thank you for the information and clarification, Mike.  My apologies for my ignorance on adding comments.  Have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is common. The buttons you add could first do an action to set a field value and then submit. The field value that's set could be a form status, which could then be used by views in the SharePoint list as well as the workflow to route the form properly.

For example, the status field could start with a value of draft. When the first button is clicked, it could change that field to "pending travel coordinator". Again, this is now available for views, and the workflow could use that value to determine who needs to be notified.